# WordPress Permalink Problem

Tags: permalinks, html

I have a blog with 3,000 post permalink using the "% postname%" now I want to change it and make it into html "% postname% .html". Everything works except for the old link on facebook and in the various social networks that unfortunately no longer open their pages. How can I do?
A change via .htaccess?

Comment: Little sidetrack - may I ask why you changed that in the first place? If someone told you this helps with SEO in any way forget it. Other than that what you are looking for is called a "redirect" and has already been explained here on WPSE plenty of times.

Comment: I am a webmaster and I need this change.

Comment: You want it, that is clear, why it is not. Most of us are also webmasters and most of us think that the change you "need" is worthless, that is why we ask you the reason to make the change and that make you think that you "need" it. Additionally, it is not a problem specifically related with WordPress.

Comment: Cloudflare caches only static content in .html, are often the victim of attacks ddos and the site goes down, I contact cloudflare and they told me to put content in .html format. In this way, the site will be visible at all times thanks to caching cloudflare

Comment: I am highly not confident that changing permalink is what they _meant_ by that. The point of HTML and static pages is much lighter load on server. Adding `.html` to dynamic page helps nothing and creates issues.